# The cap.release() function works strangely

Tags: python, opencv

I want to get a video stream from a webcam, I'm writing this code in opencv:

```py
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    frame, ret = cap.read()
    cv.resize(frame, (640, 480))

    if ret is None:
        print("Error reading frame")
        break

    cv.imshow("frame", frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

and I get the following result, it shouldn't work like this

[image]

I tested opencv on Windows 10, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, python 3.10, 3.9 on the latest version of opencv and opencv-contrib

Comment: "`cap.release()` function works strangely" -- huh? First of all, it's completely redundant here, just like `destroyAllWindows()`. Second, if you have the window up, you're still in the `while` loop, so it didn't even get called. Third, `cap.read()` returns a tuple of (status, image) -- you got them swapped, so your image is initially a single boolean. It will be treated as a 1x1 grayscale image, but the result will be meaningless. Fourth, `if ret is None` would be wrong, since `ret` will be either `True` or `False`. Fifth, the test is too late, since you already called `cv.resize` with `frame`

Comment: ... if `cap.read()` actually failed, by the time you got to the test, you program would have already crashed due to trying to resize an empty image.

Comment: I fixed the code following your comments and everything worked thanks! @DanMašek

Comment: if you don't catch the return value of `resize()`, you aren't gonna get that resized frame.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz. That is not the problem. The problem is frame, ret = cap.read()

Comment: I didn't say it were the cause of the issue OP is asking about. it's another issue that OP should be aware of. -- you might wanna give credit in your answer to who originally pointed out the issues and fixes.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to get a video stream from a webcam

There are two way to do:

Option 1
`ret` must be always first variable not the second variable.

Swap this `frame, ret = cap.read()`  to  `ret, frame = cap.read()`

That why you are using `if ret is None:`

Snippet:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read() #<== change
    cv.resize(frame, (640, 480))

    if ret is None: #<== change
        print("Error reading frame")
        break

    cv.imshow("frame", frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Option 2:
Using same OP's script.

- On line 9, change `ret` to `frame`
- On line 13, change `frame` to `ret`

Snippet:

```
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    frame, ret = cap.read()
    cv.resize(frame, (640, 480))

    if frame is None: #<== change
        print("Error reading frame")
        break

    cv.imshow("frame", ret) #<== change

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the mixup of variables was pointed out in the comments by Dan Mašek. -- this answer still puts access to the image *before checking* whether it's actually valid (also pointed out but not reflected in this answer). -- and the result of the resize() isn't actually kept. -- "option 2" just carries on with mixed up variable names. I see no way to recommend or even mention that in good conscience.